# Bringing MAX on SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have read some other posts, but none of them would completely respond my question.

I managed to generate the following select:

```
SELECT regions.id, regions.name, auditoria_status from regions
LEFT OUTER JOIN regions regions_regions ON regions_regions.id = regions.parent_id
JOIN(
    SELECT auditoria.entidade_id, auditoria.entidade_tipo, MAX(auditoria.status) AS auditoria_status 
    from auditoria GROUP BY auditoria.entidade_id, auditoria.entidade_tipo
) AS a
ON a.entidade_id = regions.id AND a.entidade_tipo = 'Terceiro' ORDER BY regions.id
```

This will list all my regions correctly. Bu I expected auditoria_status to bring me the maximum value of auditoria.status.

One of the regions record has 3 entries in the auditoria table. One with status 0, one with status 1 and the third with status 2. I was expecting to get this region id, it's name and 2 as it's auditoria_status, but gives me 0.

My goal is to list all regions (with no repeating) but bringing only the maximum status of the table auditoria for that region

**EDIT**

Ok, this SQL actually works, the dummy guy here have mistyped the entidade_tipo condition that should be 'Region' and not 'Terceiro'. So, it works.

Comment: All you did was join your subquery, you didn't actually filter by it.

Comment: When you run the subquery with the `max(auditoria.status)` what are the results?  What is the table structure of the `regions` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you did was join your subquery, you didn't actually filter by it.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, and if all you need is its id, name, and maximum status, you can just do:

```
SELECT
   regions.*, a.max_status
FROM
   regions
JOIN
   (SELECT id, MAX(status) as max_status
    FROM auditoria WHERE entidade_tipo = 'Terceiro'
    GROUP BY id) AS a 
 ON
   regions.id = a.id
ORDER BY regions.id
```

Comment: Error from PostgreSQL:
`ERROR:  column "regions.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT regions.id, regions.name, MAX(auditoria.status)`

And the other problem is that I've put only name and id just to illustrate. The most correct would be regions.* (I use all attributes from regions). 

And doing that makes PG return error for every attribute which is not in the group by clause

Comment: Sorry about the error, it's silly because it's one-to-one but still correct.  Give me a second to update.

Comment: My JOIN condition is `a.entidade_id = regions.id AND a.entidade_tipo = 'Terceiro'` and not `regions.id = a.id`, but I managed to make it work.

Comment: Note the `WHERE` condition in the subquery.